# How do you find out where your python interpreter is within python?

Tags: python

I have a system with many versions of python. Some are 32b some 64b, some 2.4 some 2.7, etc. I am working with a python script  that needs to run another python script. I want to run the 2nd script with the same version of python that the initial script was run with.

My plan is to do something like this:

```
os.system('%s script.py' % currentPython)
```

The question is: How do I define "currentPython"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path to the python interpreter is accessible as [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

Please use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to call a sub-interpreter, and not `os.system()`.

Answer (score 3):

[**`sys.executable`**](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable) contains the path you're looking for. However, you should not use `os.system`, as that path may contain spaces (for example in `C:\Program Files\Python2.7\python.exe`). Instead, use [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'script.py'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable). It gives

> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the
>   Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Panda3D-1.7.2\\python\\python.exe'
>>>
```